# Error while parsing json data in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to display data received from a json data source. But I am getting an error when I try to parse the data. I am not able to figure out how to solve it.

The json data looks something like this:

[click here to view](http://srm-news-bot.herokuapp.com/)

Here is the function I wrote for parsing :

```
public void makeJSONRequest() {
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint_final,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    // UI
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject newsItems = object.getJSONObject("newsItems");
                            for (int j = 0; j < newsItems.length(); j++) {
                                titles[j] = newsItems.getString("title");
                                snips[j] = newsItems.getString("snip");
                                links[j] = newsItems.getString("link");
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JSON Parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error Receiving News", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    InitializeVolley.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

The error I am getting is :

> Error: org.json.JSONException: Value {"newsItems":[{"link":"http://www.srmuniv.ac.in/announcement/special-training-details","snip":"Dear Students,Those who are interested in Placements must follow certain guidelines.You have to clear the tests conducted by CDC and only those...","title":"CDC: Special Training - Updated"}....

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: show us more of your logcat

Comment: I thing that `newItems` is not a JSONObject but JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

First of all this json is not an array, it is an object. You should use JsonObjectRequest instead of JsonArrayRequest. You were parsing the json wrongly.

```
public void makeJSONRequest() {
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(endpoint_final,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                // UI
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                JSONArray newsAr = response.getJsonArray("news");
                for (int i = 0; i < newsAr.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject newsItem = newsAr.getJSONObject(i);
                        titles[j] = newsItem.getString("title");
                        snips[j] = newsItem.getString("snip");
                        links[j] = newsItem.getString("link");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JSON Parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error Receiving News", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

// Adding request to request queue
InitializeVolley.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. After implementing this code, Android Studio gives me an error saying "error: incompatible types: JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray. error: no suitable constructor found for JsonObjectRequest(String,<anonymous Listener<JSONObject>>,<anonymous ErrorListener>)
constructor JsonObjectRequest.JsonObjectRequest(int,String,JSONObject,Listener<JSONObject>,ErrorListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor" What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject newsItems = object.getJSONObject("newsItems");
```

replace with

```
JSONArray newsItems = object.getJSONArray("newsItems");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject object =new JSONObject[response];
JSONArray newsItems = object.getJSONArray("newsItems");

for (int j = 0; j < newsItems.length(); j++) {

    JsonObject internal=newsItems.getJsonObject(j);
    titles[j] = internal.getString("title");
    snips[j] = internal.getString("snip");
    links[j] = internal.getString("link");
}
```

Use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` class as `newsItems` is `JsonArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public void makeJSONRequest() {
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint_final,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    // UI
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    jo = new JSONObject(response);;
                    JSONArray array = jo.getJSONArray("newsItems");
                    for (int x = 0; x < array.length(); x++) {
                        try {
                            titles[j] = array.getJSONObject(x).optString("title");
                            snips[j]= array.getJSONObject(x).optString("snip");
                            links[j] = array.getJSONObject(x).optString("link");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JSON Parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, 
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error Receiving News", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );

    // Adding request to request queue
    InitializeVolley.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own parsing function you could (and definitely should) use a library which does the heavy lifting for you. One example would be Google's Gson library, check it out: https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

Parse like :

```
try {
    JSONObject objResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    JsonArray arrResponse = objResponse.getJSONArray("newsItems");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrResponse.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject objItems = arrResponse.get(i);
        String link = objItems.getString("link");
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```